# Measure gps distance

Tags: gps, java

Here's my problem: a smartphone will send to my server some gps coordinates (latitude,longitude,altitude) and I'll have to compare these to an address stored in db in order to see how much distance there is between smartphone and address.
I'll need to obtain this address coordinates as well in order to do the actual comparison.

Is there a good and easy to use gps library for java?Any suggestions?

**In your answers please note that I need a way to get coordinates from an address too!! So, given an address "second street 2,New York, zip code 01245", I need to find latitude,longitude,altitude,ecc.**

Comment: Do you want "straight line" distance or distance through roads? These are two very different problems.

Comment: @SJuan76 you are right of course, but as there is no other information, we can make an educated guess that this is about a straight line distance.

Comment: What does this question have to do with GPS? Surely geospatial coordinates exist independent of a particular measuring technology.

Comment: Because, given an address, say "second street 4, New York", I have to find its coordinates too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android's `Location` class has a static method `distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results)`. You can look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/location/Location.java#Location) and use it in your program.

Comment: Conversion address--> coordinates solved by making a google api call!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at

- [A distance calculator using GeoCodes](http://blog.bhonsale.info/2010/06/distance-calculator-using-geocodes.html)
- [Distance between 2 geocodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110565/distance-between-2-geocodes)