# How to sort an array of coordinates according to proximity of a specific coordinate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gps

I have an array of random coordinates (latitude and longitude) and I would like to sort by distance according to a specific coordinate. Can anyone help me ? I have searched on internet but I wasn't able to find it. thanks in advance.

I am using the code below but is not efficient because I need to get each one coordinate by from the nearest to the farest :

```
var mapItens = ((from i in coordinatesArray
        (latitudeCurrent > i.Latitude && ((latitudeCurrent - i.Latitude) < 0.700 || (longitudeCurrent - i.Longitude) < 0.700)) ||
        (latitudeCurrent < i.Latitude && ((i.Latitude - latitudeCurrent) < 0.700 || (i.Longitude - longitudeCurrent) < 0.700)))
        select i).toList();
```

Comment: post your current code ... so that we know what's that you are trying exacly

Comment: Hi @Rahul ! Thank you for your reply, I've just updated what you sugested

Comment: I solved my issue with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12930598/2238515)

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort your points according to their distance from the point of interest.  (Let's call it 'point i'.)

That would involve invoking the `IList.Sort()` function and passing it an `IComparer`.  (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx)  The comparer is given two points, a and b, and is supposed to determine which one is "larger".

According to the definition of your problem, point a is larger than point b if the distance between a and i is larger than the distance between b and i.  So, your comparer simply calculates these two distances, and compares the distances instead of the points.

If your coordinates span over such a large geographic area that the curvature of Earth matters, then you need special a formula to calculate the distance between two points given in geographic coordinates.  That's not trivial, and people generally use libraries to do that kind of thing.

If the coordinates are confined within a small enough geographic area that the curvature of the Earth does not matter, then you can use a simple trigonometric distance formula:

distance = square-root-of( (a.x - i.x)<sup>2</sup> + (b.y - i.y)<sup>2</sup> ).

And since you don't actually care about exact distances, but only about how the distances compare against each other, you can use a hacky little trick and avoid taking the square root, the comparison will still yield the same result.